# downloading a file from my database to a specific location

Tags: android, download

I coded an android application that loads data from a mysql database to a listview in application and everything works normally.

**1. what I want:**

Among the elements coming from my server are the urls of the audio files and I would like the user to download these files by clicking on the element of the corresponding listview. for now I can not do it.

**2.what I try**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String[] url = GetJson.url;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url[i]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

when i click on an item in my listview i get this:

[image]

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do want to save your text file on specific location on memory?

Comment: no they are not text files but audio files. yes I will like to save them in a specific location in external storage.

Answer (score 0):

first you should donwload the mp3 file, then need to create folder on SD card then just store the file there.

please have a look on this code:

Step 1) Create the Download Method .

```
public String Download(String Url)
 {
  String filepath=null;
  try {
   //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
   //this is the file to be downloaded
   URL url = new URL(Url);
   //create the new connection
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   //set up some things on the connection
   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
    //and connect!
   urlConnection.connect();
   //set the path where we want to save the file
   //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
   //sd card.
   File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
   //which we want to save the file as.

   String filename= "downloadedFile.png";   // you can download to any type of file ex:.jpeg (image) ,.txt(text file),.mp3 (audio file)
   Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
   file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
   if(file.createNewFile())
   {
    file.createNewFile();
   }

   //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
   FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

   //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
   InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

   //this is the total size of the file
   int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
   //variable to store total downloaded bytes
   int downloadedSize = 0;

   //create a buffer...
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

   //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
   while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
    Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;

   }
   //close the output stream when done
   fileOutput.close();
   if(downloadedSize==totalSize)   filepath=file.getPath();

  //catch some possible errors...
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   filepath=null;
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;

  return filepath;

 }
```

ref-http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/download-from-internet-and-save-to-sd.html

and please use Asynctask for baground operation.

Comment: I tried your code but when I click on my listview nothing happens

Comment: Check on your dscard image is downloaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
String url=GetJson.url[i];//your audiofile url came from server
    int fsize;
    /*create a directory to store your files. declare it globally so that it will be accessible from any class in app*/
    File directory = new File((getExternalFilesDir(null)!=null?getExternalFilesDir(null):getFilesDir().getPath()) +"/"+ getPackageName()+"/dirName/");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(directory, "fileName");
    if(file.exists() && file.length()==0){
        file.delete();
    }
    if(!file.exists()){
        try
        {
            URL ur=new URL(url);
            fsize=ur.openConnection().getContentLength();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(ur.openStream());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];//as par requirement
            int length;

            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            while ((length = dis.read(buffer))>0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            fos.flush();
            dis.close();
            fos.close();
            if(file.length()<fsize){
                if(file.exists())
                    file.delete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but when I click on my listview nothing happens

Comment: I just posted the code to download a file. Put the above code in asynctask doInBackground(). And in onpostexecute() open your downloaded file from the respective path   
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 111);